# to set 12:30 PM default in mdTimePicker

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I am using mdtimepicker() function for choosing the time on web. when i am choosing a time it shows me the select one. but when i reload it again shows me the current time of the system in timepicker. and i want when i click on time picker it show me the selected time again. for example i want to set 12:30 PM default when i click to choose time. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txV3t.png)

in this image time always selected as current and i want to select time that i provide.

Comment: don't give a link, paste code here!

Comment: what... i din't understand

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function (){

  //time pickers
  $('#openingTime').mdtimepicker();
  $('#closingTime').mdtimepicker();  

 
});
</script>

Comment: <input type="text" id="openingTime" name="opening" ><input type="text" id="closingTime" name="closing" >

Comment: paste code below your question. read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Hi "AJAY DEV", welcome to StackOverflow! I see that you haven't seen/read through [StackOverflow's Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), which should inform you what StackOverflow is about, as well as how to ask a question.